# Android - Change visibility of sub-layout on listview item click

Tags: android, listview

I'd like to change the visibility of a sub-layout called `eventInformations` in my listview adapter when I'm clicking on the corresponding item.

Here's my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_view_padding_top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_view_padding_bottom"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_view_padding_right"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_view_padding_left">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eventInformations"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/eventPopup">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
        </View>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/eventActionBtn"
            android:text="@string/planning_action_register"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my `ListView` :

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/eventList"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" />
```

And here's my `OnClick` event handler :

```
eventListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        LinearLayout eventPopup = (LinearLayout)parent.getAdapter().getView(position, view, parent).findViewById(R.id.eventPopup);
        if (eventPopup.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            eventPopup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else
            eventPopup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

It is working somewhat properly, but I'm having 2 issues :

- When the sub-layout is displayed, I cannot click back on the listview
  item in order to hide it.
- When I scroll down the listview, the selected item changes randomly...

I can't seem to find why it's working that way.

Thanks.

Comment: lets see you layout of the list view

Comment: Added it to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the sub-layout is displayed, I cannot click back on the listview
>   item in order to hide it.

The problem may be that your visible `sublayout` contains some focussable view, which is intercepting the click event for your `ListView onItemClick()` .

**Solution :**

Instead of using `ListView onItemClick()`. Try `onClickListener()` method on corresponding view in your `ListView Adapter` on whose click you want to hide/unhide your `sublayout`

> When I scroll down the listview, the selected item changes randomly...

This is happening because your views are getting recycled/reuse and hence the problem.

**Solution :**

I am assuming you have a List of Custom objects that you are passing to your `ListView Adapter` represented as

```
List<Modal> modalsList=new ArrayList<Modal>();
```

In order to maintain the visibility state of your `sublayout`, take a flag inside your modal class, For example

```
private boolean isVisible;
```

and include corresponding getter and setter for these

```
public boolean isVisible() {
        return isVisible;
    }

    public void setIsVisible(boolean isVisible) {
        this.isVisible = isVisible;
    }
```

and in your `getView()` method of your `ListView Adapter`, manage the visibility of your `sublayout` using this flag

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_item, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder= new ViewHolder(convertView);// initialise all your views inside the ViewHolder Constructor
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Modal modal= modalsList.get(position);
        if(modal.isVisible()){
          // enable visibility of your sublayout
        }else{
          // disable visibility of your sublayout
        }

        // apply onClickListener on your correspoding view on whose click you want to toggle your sublayout visibility

        viewHolder.btToggleVisibility
                            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    // toggle isVisible flag for your corresponding modal
                                    if(modal.isVisible()){
                                        modal.setIsVisible(false);
                                    }else{
                                        modal.setIsVisible(true);
                                    }
                                    // update your modal list for that particular position and notify the adapter
                                    modalList.set(position,modal);
                                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            });
}
```

Hope this will help you. Let me know if any issues.

Comment: Working, thanks. I think this mecanisme of recycling views without storing their attributes is the most stupid I've ever seen, it almost feels like a bug to me...

Comment: Well reusing views is one of the most powerful feature of ListView. In ListView , it is optional but when you move to RecyclerView, the more advanced and efficient version of ListView, you have to stick to recycling of views. Anyways glad it worked for you :)

Comment: Thanks Mukesh, I don't have chance to use RecylerView because my app min target is API 16 upto max 23, So your solutions is exactly working fine.Thanks for contribution.

Comment: I have issue in sub-layout, it contains edit ext, i can't read the entered text value, can you please guide me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't what do you mean in real. but I feel you want your listView items have child that after click on an item you open and close it. let me if I think wrong but to do this you can use expandableListView. here is an example of adapter for it:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter2(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                              HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this.context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.title.setText(childText);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_group, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.title.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
}
}
```

anyway if you want to save a position of listView you can save data in adapeter and load it again in getView method. for example you want to save state of some checkable item you can use an array of boolean:

```
    private boolean[] itemTF;
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.score_list_item, null, false);
    TextView textView15 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView15);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    if (itemTF[position])
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
    else checkBox.setChecked(false);

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            itemTF[position] = isChecked;
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```